# Scheme Inserting Pairs into Heap

Tags: recursion, data-structures, scheme, heap

This is part of a homework assignment that I can't seem to figure out.  I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction?

The problem reads:

> `(insert-list-of-pairs vw-pair-list heap)` evaluates to the *heap* resulting from inserting
>   all of the *value*-*weight* pairs from the list `vw-pair-list` into the heap `heap`.

The following functions were created earlier in the homework for use in this problem:

```
(define (create-heap vw-pair left right)
    (list vw-pair left right))

(define (h-min heap)
    (car heap))

(define (left heap)
    (cadr heap))

(define (right heap)
    (caddr heap))
```

In the previous problem I was able to successfully add a pair to the heap using this code:

```
(define (insert vw-pair heap)
    (if (null? heap)
        (create-heap vw-pair '() '())
        (if (< (weight vw-pair) (weight (h-min heap)))
            (create-heap vw-pair (right heap) (insert (h-min heap) (left heap)))
            (create-heap (h-min heap) (right heap) (insert vw-pair (left heap))))))
```

I tried to implement a similar procedure using the following code without success:

```
(define (insert-list-of-pairs vw-pair-list heap)
    (if (null? vw-pair-list)
        heap
        (if (< (car vw-pair-list) (h-min heap))
            (create-heap (car vw-pair-list) (right heap) 
                          (insert-list-of-pairs (cdr vw-pair-list) heap))
            (create-heap (h-min heap) (right heap) 
                          (insert-list-of-pairs vw-pair-list heap)))))
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good reasons that your previous problem was defining `insert`.
Not only do you now know how to implement `insert`, but you also have a function that you can use for insertion so you never need to implement it again.

Because what is a list of such pairs?

If it's not empty, it's one pair followed by a list of pairs.
And you already have a function that inserts one pair into a heap.

If only you had a function that inserts a list of pairs into a heap, you could use that to insert the rest of your list into your heap, then `insert` your list's first element into *that* heap, and then you would be done.

But - Eureka! - the "insert a list of pairs into a heap" function is the one you're writing.
So, you recurse:

```
(define (insert-list-of-pairs vw-pair-list heap)
    (if (null? vw-pair-list)
        heap
        (insert (car vw-pair-list)
                (insert-list-of-pairs (cdr vw-pair-list) heap))))
```

and then you're done.