# Scheme - Inserting into Binary Heap vs Binary Search Tree

Tags: scheme, racket

Previously, I've worked on an exercise for a homework assignment implementing a Binary Search Tree in scheme, and now I'm trying to convert this code into a heap. What I'm struggling with is finding the correct position to insert a new element into the heap. In a Binary search tree, we simply using a predicate navigate through the tree comparing against each node going left or right.

```
(define (bst-insert bst f x)
  (cond ((bst-is-empty? bst) (bst-create x
                                         (bst-create-empty)
                                         (bst-create-empty)))
        ((f x (bst-root bst)) (bst-create (bst-root bst)
                                          (bst-insert (bst-left bst) f x)
                                          (bst-right bst)))
        (else (bst-create (bst-root bst)
                          (bst-left bst)
                          (bst-insert (bst-right bst) f x)))))
```

Where f is our predicate function here. But for a heap we are supposed to insert at the next available location. Is there a trick I'm missing to in order to find this next location?

Edit:

```
(define heap-create list)

(define (heap-create-empty) '())

(define heap-root car)

(define heap-left cadr)

(define heap-right caddr)

(define heap-is-empty? null?)

(define (heap-insert h f x)
  (if (null? h) (heap-create x (heap-create-empty) (heap-create-empty))
      (let ((h (heap-root h)))
        (if (f x h) (heap-create x (heap-right h) (heap-insert (heap-left h) f h))
            (heap-create h (heap-right h) (heap-insert (heap-left) f x))))))

(define (list->heap xs f)
  (heap-insert (heap-create) xs f))
```

So I've posted my current code above here, I think I'm closer but something is wrong as the output I'm receiving is `'(#<procedure:<> () ())` When calling `(list->heap '(3 1 5 9 8 2 7 4 6) <)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046147/scheme-inserting-pairs-into-heap) builds the heap by alternating the left and right subtrees: when inserting a new element, make (min old_root new_value) the root, make the old *right* subtree the new *left* subtree, and insert (max old_root new_value) into *the old left* subtree and make that *the new right* subtree. (Where min and max assume that < is the predicate).

The insertion is always done in the right subtree, but as the subtrees are swapped each time, the height of the left and right subtrees will be kept in balance. As the heap property does not require that the order of elements is preserved this is fine.

As example, inserting the sequences 1 2 3 4 5 1 and 5 4 3 2 1 6 in a min-heap:

```
        1                     5

        1                     4                   
       / \                   / \
          2                     5

         1                    3
        / \                  / \ 
       2   3                5   4

         1                    2
        / \                  / \
       3   2                4   3
      /\  / \              /\    \
             4                    5

         1                    1
        / \                  / \
       2   3                3   2
      / \   \              / \   \
         4   5                5   4

          1                    1
        /   \                 / \
       3     1               2   3 
      /\    / \             /\   /\
        5  4   2              4 5  6
```

With the predicate as a parameter `f`, `insert` can be written as:

```
(define (insert heap f val)
  (if (null? heap)
      (make-heap val '() '())
  (let ((h (first heap)))
    (if (f val h)
        (make-heap val (right heap) (insert (left heap) f h ))
        (make-heap h (right heap) (insert (left heap) f val))))))
```

with

```
(define (make-heap val l r)
  (list val l r))
```

and

```
(define (left heap)
  (cadr heap))

(define (right heap)
  (caddr heap))
```

Another "trick" is to use a vector to implement the heap, as done in the [racket/data/](https://github.com/racket/data/blob/master/data-lib/data/heap.rkt) heap. This is more efficient as no pointers need to be stored and the positions of a child/parent of a node is a function of the node's index in the vector (see the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))).

**Update:** In response to the edit with non-working code:

The `#<procedure:<>` element at the head of the list is the `<` function (the repl output may be a bit confusing here, it is actually `procdeure:<` surrounded by `<>`), as illustrated by

```
> (define foo (list->heap '(3 1 5 9 8 2 7 4 6) <))
> foo
'(#<procedure:<> () ())
> (car foo)
#<procedure:<>
> ((car foo) 1 2)
#t
> ((car foo) 2 1)
#f
```

The cause is that the arguments are passed in the wrong order: the predicate is the second argument to your `heap-insert` function. Thus, `heap-insert` uses `<` as the value to insert.

Regarding `list->heap`, it should be recursive to insert the elements in the list one by one (see the answer to the linked question). With this definition (swapping the order of arguments) it gives

```
> (list->heap '(3 1 5 9 8 2 7 4 6) <)
'((3 1 5 9 8 2 7 4 6) () ())
```

as this is simply

```
> (heap-insert (heap-create) < '(3 1 5 9 8 2 7 4 6))
```

or

```
> (heap-create '(3 1 5 9 8 2 7 4 6) (heap-create-empty) (heap-create-empty))
```

which is equivalent to

```
> ( list  '(3 1 5 9 8 2 7 4 6) (heap-create-empty) (heap-create-empty))
'((3 1 5 9 8 2 7 4 6) () ())
```

Comment: So a few things I was hoping you could clarify: 1) I was reading the link you provided, as well as the code above and I guess I'm confused on how its alternating which tree the new value is being inserted in. Unless I misread, in the link it was being inserted more like a Binary Search Tree going left on right based on comparing to the root node or I am I misunderstanding the code? 2) Let has and still is a little confused to me in some cases I understand it, in others I don't fully follow. I'm not sure exactly what (let ((h (first heap)) is doing in the code you provided.

Comment: I added an example building a heap.
Regarding `let`, it just binds a value to a local name. In this case, you can remove the `let` and  replace `h` with `(first heap)` in the two `make-heap` expressions.

Comment: Added a sentence of explanation. Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Yes this makes it much clearer. Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: You're welcome.  Consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, I think I'm closer but maybe didn't understand as much as I thought. I've updated my main post with current progress as well as the output I think I might be create the empty heaps wrong?

Comment: @drRobertz I know this is a long shot since this post is 3 years old, but was wondering if you could explain exactly how to list->heap function recursive, as you specify that is necessary in your answer.

Comment: @WesleyBrandt I believe the answer to the linked question answers that.